# Table of contents does not appear in the left sidebar in Jupyterlab 3.4.2

Tags: jupyter-lab

The table of contents extension is built-in JupyterLab since version 3.0. Howerver, there is no TOC in the left sidebar of my jupyterlab. How can I make my TOC appear properly? Thanks.

left sidebar:

[image: left sidebar]

settings:

[image: settings]

Comment: Do you have a notebook with markdown headings open?

Answer (score 4):

For me, the following screenshot resolved the issue,
that is to untick the "include cell output in headings" from the theme tab - Table of Contents, in the settings.

Settings → Table of Contents:

[image]